# Get frame in player animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I find the frame of the current animation that is playing in the scene? For example, I want to transform the player up for the first part of a jump animation, and transform them down for the second half (Say, when the frame is greater than 35 and less than 60). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a specific animation frame, you should use
`animation["anim_name"].time` (it's a **float**).
You can also set it with saying:
`animation["anim_name"].time = [float_value]` (and play with `.Play`).
But instead of doing this for the problem you describe, why don't you create two animation clips (even from the same anim) and name them let's say "jump" and "fall" and put together a [Mecanim Locomotion](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/MecanimAnimationSystem.html)?

Comment: I'm not the best at animations, so that was my solution, but I will look into the Jump and Fall one too. For now though, thanks!